# Malformed JSON: Expected '[': how to deserialize JSON with REST API?

Tags: rest-api, json, rest, deserialize

Error: `Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set`

I think I have incorrect `JSON.deserialize` for my object. How can I fix it? I don't use a wrapper.

```
List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
public static HttpRequest createRequestForService(){
    HttpRequest finalRequest = new HttpRequest();
    finalRequest.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + 'my_token_here');
    finalRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    finalRequest.setHeader('accept','application/json');
    finalRequest.setMethod('GET');
    finalRequest.setEndpoint('https://name.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/query/?q=SELECT+Name+FROM+AnotherObject__c);
    return finalRequest;
}
//My code here
//and incorrect deserialization (Error is here):
accList = (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(responseService.getBody(), List<Account>.class);
```

Comment: Hmm you're trying to deserialize something that isnt list of accounts into list of accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API uses a wrapper itself, so you need to obey the rules. A proper response looks something like this:

```
public class RestResponseWrapper {
  public Integer totalSize;
  public Boolean done;
  public String nextRecordsUrl;
  public SObject[] records; // note: change to specific SObject type
}
```

You can read more about the query resource in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm).

---

```
accList = ((RestResponseWrapper)
  JSON.deserialize(responseService.getBody(), RestResponseWrapper.class)).records;
```